# Get element's selector from element method

Tags: javascript, html

I have [data-targer="this.nextSibling"] in the element which I wanted to fire onClick to change its value.

Is is possible to use selector in [data-target] ?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emad/aq9Laaew/266336/)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <button class="col btn btn-danger" onClick="makeLess()" data-targer="this.nextSibling">
            <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
            </button>
    <div class="col text-right">
      0
    </div>
      <button class="col btn btn-primary" onClick="makeMore()" data-target="this.previousSibling">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </button>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Can I use 'data-target' to store other-element selector!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the selector. There is a typo in your code `data-targer`,
and secondly you need to pass the element reference in onClick to use the element attribute.

Anyways, you need to use previousElementSibling and nextElementSibling to access the element on the same tree level.

In case, you just want to update the count "0" without doing anything with the element attributes, you don't need to pass reference of elements.

You can use following.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <button class="col btn btn-danger" onClick="makeLess(this)" data-target="this.nextElementSibling">
            <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
            </button>
    <div class="col text-right">
     0
    </div>
      <button class="col btn btn-primary" onClick="makeMore(this)" data-target="this.previousElementSibling">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </button>
  </div>  
</div>
 <script>

 function makeLess(e)   {
  var target = e.nextElementSibling;
  target.innerHTML--;
}

function makeMore(e)    {
  var target = e.previousElementSibling;
  target.innerHTML++;
}
 </script>
```

Here is the jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/sf5c3kgy/5/

Comment: Why you need element reference? You can delete half of your code and it will still working https://jsfiddle.net/nerkicacy/8aqrnuL1/ . But I don't think it is answer that he wanted. He want to get element without specifying id

Comment: Good point. As mentioned, Element reference is required in order to access the element attributes.  Otherwise methods can be called directly if OP doesn't want to do anything with the element(from where event is triggered)

Comment: I wanted to use what's in data-target string which contains the element selector

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are many things wrong in your code.

- [nextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/nextSibling) and [previousSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/previousSibling) will not work, beacuse that method return also text nodes. You need to use [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) and [previousElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling) for returning actual element.
- javascript code in data-attributes will also not work. For interpreter it is just text (string), and not code to execute. You can try use it with [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), but it is bad pattern, and should be avoided.
- Also, "this" inside your function point to "window" element, and not to button that is being clicked. To get reference you need to pass button as function argument `onClick="makeMore(this)"`

So, it should look like this (similar as Nishu wrote above):

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <button class="col btn btn-danger" onClick="makeLess(this)">
            <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="col text-right">
           0
        </div>
        <button class="col btn btn-primary" onClick="makeMore(this)">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
        </button>
    </div>  
</div>
```

JS

```
function makeLess(target)   {
    target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML--
}

function makeMore(target)   {
    target.previousElementSibling.innerHTML++
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nerkicacy/adr4mueg/2/)

One more thing: mixing HTML and JS is usually bad, it should be avoided if possible. It is better to get element by `document.getElementById`, or `element.querySelector` and then attach event using `element.addEventListener`.

Comment: I wanted to use the [selector] string inside data-target.